# simple php strpos does not find value

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a substring like this:

```
// get needle for strpos
$someStringContainingHtmlTags = '<table><td class="size1of2 bold">Order no</td></div><td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">64210</td></table>';

$re = '/<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">\d+<\/td>/';
preg_match($re, $someStringContainingHtmlTags , $matches);

$art = (string)$matches[0];

$needle = '<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">'.$art.'</td>';

// echos nothing
echo strpos($someStringContainingHtmlTags , $needle);
```

If I replace $art with actual value `64210`, `strpos` works.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please add relevant code for `$str` variable.

Comment: I have already did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sir McPotato told you need to put expression into group. Second element of `matches` will return `64210`

```
<?php
// get needle for strpos
$someStringContainingHtmlTags  = '<table><td class="size1of2 bold">Order no</td></div><td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">64210</td></table>';

$re = '/<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">(\d+)<\/td>/';
preg_match($re, $someStringContainingHtmlTags , $matches);

$art = (string)$matches[1];

$needle = '<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">'.$art.'</td>';

// echos nothing
echo strpos($someStringContainingHtmlTags , $needle);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I thought, that `$matches[0]` contains my value...

Answer (score 1):

In order tou get your `$art`the correct value (64210), you should put the `\d` into a group : `$re = '/<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">(\d+)<\/td>/';`

Comment: I do find `$art` correctly with `preg_match`, I cannot find `'<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">'.$art.'</td>'` using `strpos`

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
$someStringContainingHtmlTags = '<table><td class="size1of2 bold">Order no</td></div><td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">64210</td></table>';
$re = '/<td class="size1of2" data-template="productBestnr">\d+<\/td>/';
preg_match($re, $someStringContainingHtmlTags , $matches);
$art = (string)$matches[0];
// echos nothing
echo strpos($someStringContainingHtmlTags , $art);
```

Your $art is actually your needle. And you were adding niddle inside needle.

Once echo $art you will get it.

Comment: I need to find complete string with html tags, and `$art` will be added dynamiclly, so I store it in a variable

Comment: Do you want to fetch value 64210 ?

Comment: I want to find pos of a string which contains `$art` withing a bigger string

Comment: So what's the problem with my answer ? It is doing the same thing right ?

Comment: rahul, you are finding the position of `$re` inside `$someStringContainingHtmlTags`. This is not what OP was looking for